# No margin for last column

Tags: html, css

I have four columns inside a wrapper centered in the body . I need margin between the three columns but no margin to the right of the last column .

```css
    .footer-top {
        width :960px ;
        margin : 40px auto 30px ;
        overflow:hidden;
        border:solid;
    }
    
    .column1 , .column2,.column3 ,.column4  {
        float : left ;
        width:20%;
        margin-right:3%;   
    }
    
    .column1 p {
        margin:30px 0;
    } 
    
    .column4:last-child {
        margin-right:0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class = "footer-top">
                        <div class= "column1">
                            <h4>LITTLE ABOUT US </h4>
                            <p>Et veniam exquisitaque. Ab culpa anim aut senserit, quo appellat coniunctione. 
                             Cernantur amet aliqua</p>
    
                             <div class = "social">
                                <h4>Follow us</h4>
                                 <ul>
                                     <li><a href="#" class="facebook"></a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#" class="twitter"></a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#" class="rss"></a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#" class="vimeo"></a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#" class="dribble"></a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#" class="msn"></a></li>
                                 </ul>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "column2">
                            <h4>ARCHIVES</h4>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href=" ">March 2016</a></li>
                                <li><a href = " ">February 2012</a></li>
                                <li><a href =" ">January 2016</a></li>
                                <li><a href = " ">December 2016</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "column3">
                           <h4>CONTACT US </h4>
                        </div>
                         <div class = "column4"  >
                            <h4>SIGN TO NEWSLETTER</h4>
                         </div>
                  </div>
```

I am new to CSS and have not used the last-child selector before . This doesnt seem to be working . I am assuming the selector is checking if .column4 is the last sibling of other column4 elements in the HTML . Am I correct in my understanding ? Also what would be the way to achieve no margin to the right of the last column ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems

1. You can just target `.column4{}` or `.footer-top div:last-child{}`
2. Small math problem

You got 4 elements, that 25% width for each.
Minus 3% margin right you added, that gives 22% width for each.
If you remove the right-padding of the last itme, you have 3% of width remaining. So that add .75% of width to each element. As a result you whant 22.75% of width for each column

```
.column1,
.column2,
.column3,
.column4 {
  float: left;
  width: 22.75%;
  margin-right: 3%;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

```css
.footer-top {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 40px auto 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid;
}

.column1,
.column2,
.column3,
.column4 {
  float: left;
  width: 22.75%;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

.column1 p {
  margin: 30px 0;
}


.footer-top div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="footer-top">
  <div class="column1">
    <h4>LITTLE ABOUT US </h4>
    <p>Et veniam exquisitaque. Ab culpa anim aut senserit, quo appellat coniunctione. Cernantur amet aliqua</p>

    <div class="social">
      <h4>Follow us</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="facebook"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="twitter"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="rss"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="vimeo"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dribble"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="msn"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <h4>ARCHIVES</h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=" ">March 2016</a></li>
      <li><a href=" ">February 2012</a></li>
      <li><a href=" ">January 2016</a></li>
      <li><a href=" ">December 2016</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="column3">
    <h4>CONTACT US </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="column4">
    <h4>SIGN TO NEWSLETTER</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes flexboxes would be my way to go. But he mention he was new to CSS, in this case giving a solution was priority. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Gerrardo . I learned a lot from your answer . I skipped the flexbox part from the book I am learning from and would surely look into it in some time .

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use :last-child since you have a specific selector for the last column. Simply use:

```
.column4 {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

A simpler way to do this may be:

HTML:

```
<div class="footer-top">
    <div class="column">
        <!--column 1 content-->
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <!--column 2 content-->
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <!--column 3 content-->
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <!--column 4 content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer-top {
    width :960px ;
    margin : 40px auto 30px ;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:solid;
}

.column {
    float : left ;
    width:20%;
    margin-right:3%;   
}

.column:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

CPR

Comment: The way I see it, this is a question about CSS, which I have answered. Please refer to the original post

Comment: Yes, it's a CSS problem but your solution does not solve the issue..try it and see.